# TaskCompletionSource deadlock?

Tags: c#

I used TaskCompletionSource in consuming WCF service by which I don't have code access. Because if I will just consume directly the method on their service without using TaskCompletionSource it will not return any records.

On my web api action I have this

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<IList<Details>> GetDetails()
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IList<Details>>();
  ServiceProxy.Instance.ListDetailsAsync((Exception ex,List<Details> details, 
  object obj)=>
  {
     tcs.SetResult(details);
  }, null);
 return tcs.Task;
}
```

The ServiceProxy they created shows like this

```
public void ListDetailsAsync(Action<Exception, List<Details>, object> final, object context)
{
    CallClient<object, List<string>, List<Details>>("Get all details", null, final, context, DetailsReadAll_Call);
}

void DetailsReadAll_Call(WCFServiceClient client, object input1, object detailsState)
{
    client.GetAllDetailsCompleted += GetAllDetails_Completed;
    client.GetAllDetailsAsync(detailsState);
}

void GetAllDetails_Completed(object sender, GetAllDetailsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   var detailsState = (DetailState<List<string>, List<Details>>)e.DetailState;

   detailsState.Perform(e.Error, e.dex, delegate() { return e.Result.ToList(); }, delegate(List<string> result1, out List<Details> output1)
   {
       List<Details> details= new List<Details>();

         foreach (string detailXml in result1)
         {
            details.Add(ObjectSerializer.Parse<Details>(detailXml));
         }

         output1 = details;
    });
}
```

All of these code is working fine on localhost with my VS2012 which means it returns records without any error. But when I deployed it on the server it wont return any records, and on dev tool it shows pending status. This issue is taking my whole day since I cant replicate it on VS2012 so no idea on where and why it happened. Really need help badly here.

Comment: I tried to use Task.Run on SetResult and still not working. Also tried to use async and await, not wokring also